# can I call windows api functions (64 bit) when compiling with gcc (gfortran)?

Tags: winapi, gcc, fortran, gfortran, fortran-iso-c-binding

I'm attempting to compile a subroutine sendmsg.f90 that we previously compiled with lf90 as 32 bit now with gcc as 64 bit. The purpose is to link it with other 64 bit subroutines compiled with gcc.

```
subroutine UpdateDisplay(WINHAND,NTPS,QCANCEL,NITER)
  use win32mod
  implicit none
  integer WINHAND, NTPS, MESSNUM, NITER, QCANCEL
!                SendMessageA is a Windows function
!                  WINHAND = handle of window (from ISDev code)
!                  MESSNUM = message number (assigned by ISDev)
!                  NTPS = number of year iteration currently on (WParam)
!                  DUM = 0 (LParam)  

  MESSNUM = 1114
  QCANCEL = SendMessageA(carg(WINHAND),carg(MESSNUM),carg(NTPS), carg(NITER))

end subroutine
```

We have Lahey Fortran 7.5 which has the lf90 compiler and gcc (which uses gfortran) and something called lgf (which I suppose uses gcc, is that right?).

I'm new to Windows programming (and Fortran). Can code compiled with gcc call the Windows API? Should I use ISO_C_BINDING?

Should I even do this or should I try to link the .obj file created by lf90 with the .o files created by gcc?

Thanks for your help!

Update:
I've tried calling the windows API with:

```
MODULE SND_C
    interface
        integer(C_LONG) FUNCTION SendMessage  &
            (WINHAND,MESSNUM,NTPS, NITER)  &
            bind(C,Name='SendMessage')
            use ISO_C_BINDING
            implicit NONE
            integer(C_LONG), VALUE :: WINHAND
            integer(C_LONG), VALUE :: MESSNUM
            integer(C_LONG), VALUE :: NTPS
            integer(C_LONG), VALUE :: NITER
        end function SendMessage
    end interface
END MODULE SND_C


subroutine UpdateDisplay(WINHAND,NTPS,QCANCEL,NITER)    
  USE ISO_C_BINDING, ONLY: C_LONG
  USE SND_C
  implicit none
  integer(C_LONG) WINHAND, NTPS, MESSNUM, NITER, QCANCEL
!                SendMessageA is a Windows function
!                  WINHAND = handle of window (from ISDev code)
!                  MESSNUM = message number (assigned by ISDev)
!                  NTPS = number of year iteration currently on (WParam)
!                  DUM = 0 (LParam)  

!GCC$ ATTRIBUTES DLLEXPORT :: UpdateDisplay
  MESSNUM = 1114
  QCANCEL = SendMessage(WINHAND,MESSNUM,NTPS, NITER)

end subroutine
```

but when I try to compile with "gcc -m64 sendmsg.f90" I get the error:

```
C:\Users\StephanieJ\Documents\Lahey-Fujitsu Fortran>gcc -m64 sendmsg.f90
c:/progra~2/lahey-~1/v7.5/gcc-gf~1/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/4.7.4/../..
/../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/lib/../lib/crt2.o: In function `__tmainCRTStartup':
c:\gccbuild\mingw-crt\build32-64\mingw-w64-crt/../../mingwsvn/mingw-w64-crt/crt/
crtexe.c:323: undefined reference to `__laheypause'
C:\Users\STEPHA~2\AppData\Local\Temp\ccWjjo5b.o:sendmsg.f90:(.text+0x3e): undefi
ned reference to `SendMessage'
c:/progra~2/lahey-~1/v7.5/gcc-gf~1/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/4.7.4/../..
/../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/lib/../lib/libmingw32.a(lib64_libmingw32_a-crt0_c.o):
In function `main':
c:\gccbuild\mingw-crt\build32-64\mingw-w64-crt/../../mingwsvn/mingw-w64-crt/crt/
crt0_c.c:18: undefined reference to `WinMain'
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Does this approach make sense? Why is my reference to SendMessage undefined?

Comment: You can probably call Windows 64 bit API from Fortran, but be aware the API has changed (and also the [ABI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X86_calling_conventions#Microsoft_x64_calling_convention)), so you will need a specific interface (I mean, the equivalent of windows.h).

Comment: On 64-bit, it's actually easier to call the API routines as you don't have to worry about STDCALL. All you need is the proper interface, and you could use BIND(C) to specify the mixed-case name. ISO_C_BINDING could help for kind values but probably not much. Intel Fortran provides declarations for thousands of Windows API routines - some other Windows compilers do too.

Comment: Maybe it should be SendMessageA? In Windows API, usually functions dealing with characters come in 2 versions, one ending with A (ANSI charset), the other with W (wide, i.e. unicode). In C, the name is automatically chosen (probably by macris in windows.h), not when calling from another language.

Comment: @arbautjc You are right, we needed an interface to the API. It seems that Lahey-Fortran has such a thing with their Lahey/Fujitsu compiler, but not with the Lahey/GNU Fortran. However, the workaround was to include windows.h in c wrapper and link the .o file in with the other .o files compiled from Fortran.

Comment: @Steve Lionel Yes, good point. Your [post](http://objectmix.com/fortran/299544-win32-api-gfortran.html) does a good job explaining this.

Comment: @arbautjc Thanks for explaining the difference between SendMessageA and SendMessageC. I'm a little confused as to why there would need to be two versions of SendMessage if the parameters and return value are all integers.

Comment: It's probably because of other functions called by SendMessage, for which the difference is important. Btw, see [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644950%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) for MSDN doc for SendMessage.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably the easiest way to call the API is through a C wrapper function that might look like this:

```
#include <windows.h>
void updatedisplay_(  HWND *winhand, WPARAM  *ntps, LRESULT *qcancel, LPARAM *niter)
{
  //  integer NTPS, MESSNUM, NITER, QCANCEL
  /*
  !                  WINHAND = handle of window (from ISDev code)
  !                  MESSNUM = message number (assigned by ISDev)
  !                  NTPS = number of year iteration currently on (WParam)
  !                  DUM = 0 (LParam)  
  */
  UINT messnum = 1114;
  *qcancel = SendMessage(*winhand,messnum,*ntps,*niter);
}
```

The lower case and trailing underscore are to match the Fortran default function naming.
If you suppose that the file name is updatedisplay.c, compile it with the command:

gcc -c updatedisplay.c

On the Fortran side, instead of sending zero as the window handle, use C_NULL_PTR from ISO_C_BINDING instead.
You can then link the object file updatedisplay.o with the Fortran code that originally called the Fortran function of the same name, and it should work.

To get rid of the laheypause thing, link with the file lgfpstub.o from the proper lib directory either x86_64-w64-mingw32\lib for x86_64 or x86_64-w64-mingw32\lib32 for x86.

Hope this helps!

Comment: The code above works exactly. We didn't realize that we could link the .o files compiled from fortran with the .o files compiled from c.